# Ruby on Rails - How to save foreign key in nested resources save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in Rails (and here in Stackoverflow) and I'm doing my first application. The applicatiou allow to create Excursions and manage their inscriptions in another view, using the route: excursion/:excursion_id/inscriptions etc. For this propose,I have defined two models: Excursions and Inscriptions like this:

```
class Excursion < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :inscriptions

validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :busSpots, presence: true, length: { minimum: 0 }
validates :lunchSpots, presence: true, length: { minimum: 0 }
end

class Inscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :excursion, :autosave => true

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :phoneNumber, presence: true, length: { is: 9 }
    validates :email, presence: true #Afegir regexp per a email validation.
    validates :busSpots, presence: true, length: { minimum: 0 }
    validates :lunchSpots, presence: true, length: { minimum: 0 }
end
```

After that, I defined my routes.rb this way:

```
resources :excursions do
    resources :inscriptions
end
```

This is my *index.html.erb* for excursions view:

```
<% @excursions.each do |excursion| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= excursion.name %></td>
    <td><%= excursion.busSpots %></td>
    <td><%= excursion.lunchSpots %></td>
    <td><%= excursion.active %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show details', excursion_path(excursion) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit excursion', edit_excursion_path(excursion) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete excursion', excursion_path(excursion),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show inscriptions', excursion_inscriptions_path(:excursion_id => excursion.id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Do an inscription', new_excursion_inscription_path(:excursion_id => excursion.id) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Everything is working well, but I suspect that my inscriptions controller is not receiving the :excursion_id. When I try to save an inscription I use the create method:

```
def create
    @excursion = Excursion.find(params[:excursion_id])
    @inscription = Inscription.new(inscription_params)
    @inscription.excursion_id = @excursion.id
    if @inscription.save
        redirect_to @inscription
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**When I try to save an inscription, the data is saved but the excursion_id foreign key is null on database. So my question is: What I am doing wrong? Which is the correct way to be able to use excursion.id in inscription controller?**

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I just realized that the Inscription table has 2 columns: excursions_id and excursion_id. The first is created by Rails by the model `belongs_to` label. The second column is created by the declaration of foreign key. Why is this happening? Is correct to define foreign key manually in ActiveRecord?

**EDIT2 AND SOLVED**: Finally, this issue was related to tables creation. I was creating two foreign keys in Inscriptions table. For possible future users, I have create my Inscription table this way:

```
class CreateInscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :inscriptions do |t|
            t.belongs_to :excursion, index:true, foreign_key: true
            t.string :name
            t.integer :phoneNumber
            t.string :email
            t.integer :busSpots
            t.integer :lunchSpots

            t.timestamps null: false
        end

        #THIS LINE WAS NOT NECESSARY -> add_reference :inscriptions, :excursion, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
end
```

*Thanks to Andrew Hendrie and Frederick Cheung for their help and patience.*

Comment: What you've shown looks ok. If params[:execution_id] wasn't present the code you show would raise an exception. Is that create method definitely being called ? (try adding a logger statement or breakpoint in there)

Comment: The method is being called. I have just realize that I have two foreign keys defined in Inscriptions table.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of Strong Parameters. You need to add excursion_id to the permitted parameters.

```
def excursion_params
  params.require(:excursion).permit(:name, :busStops, :lunchStops, :active, inscriptions_attributes: :excursion_id)
end
```

Comment: I have added your suggestion to excursion_params without success. I think the main problem is that excursion_id is not defined in inscription controller

Comment: The controller for excursion